# jquery graphics (ways of provide inputs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, input

I am trying to bind a JSON object to a jquery chart. In the example provided they take data statically, i.e. as following

```
var sampleData = [
                { Country: 'China', Population: 1347350000, Percent: 19.18},
                { Country: 'India', Population: 1210193422, Percent: 17.22},
                { Country: 'USA', Population: 313912000, Percent: 4.47},
                { Country: 'Indonesia', Population: 237641326, Percent: 3.38},
                { Country: 'Brazil', Population: 192376496, Percent: 2.74}];
```

For, data must be prepared in this mode because Country/Population/Percent are needed to the library.
What I have instead is a JSON object ($.getJSON...)

How can I do? Any idea? I am first at jquery so I need some help

Comment: An object created from a JSON string would be fine for this. Is there a specific issue you're having?

Comment: Hi,
If I am not wrong than you need dynamic json ? as this example gives you static. Am I right ?

Comment: You need to clarify what you have and what you need. "Who" have to prepare data, in wich form these data is provided. The question isn't clear enough